# request for member 'find' in 'm', which is of non-class type 'int'

Tags: c++, unordered-map

getting error `/code/Solution.cpp:8:14: error: request for member 'find' in 'm', which is of non-class type 'int'
if(m.find(s)!=m.end())return;`

I also tried to change the location of unordered_map to outside the class ,still getting 
the same error.

```
class Solution {
public:

    int maxsum;
    unordered_map<string,int>m;
    void solve(int m,vector<int>a,int sum,int i){
        string s = to_string(sum)+" "+to_string(i);
        if(m.find(s)!=m.end())return;
        m[s]++;
        if(i==a.size())return;

        if(sum+a[i]<m){maxsum=max(maxsum,sum+a[i]);
        solve(m,a,sum+a[i],i+1);}
        solve(m,a,sum,i+1);
    }
    int backPack(int m, vector<int> &a) {
        // write your code here
        maxsum=0;
        solve(m,a,0,0);
        return maxsum;
    }
};
```

Comment: the compiler is right. `m` Is an `int`. You have two different `m`s ...

Answer (score 1):

You called both the map class variable `m`, and the first function parameter `m`. The parameter [shadows](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/scope#Name_hiding) the class variable, so your compiler sees it instead.

You should try to avoid using the same name for multiple variables that can be seen from the same scope, and while you’re at it you might want to use more meaningful names instead of just using single letters, to make your code more readable.